# C++ what is the difference between 'int* n ' and 'int *n'?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, std

I recently switched from java to c++ and was writing these two lines of code:

```cpp
    int* a;
    int *b;
```

I'm wondering what the difference is between these two lines? I've tried searching online but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935024/what-is-the-difference-between-int-xnm-and-int-x-nm) only talks about the difference between `int (*a)` and `int* a`. Or is `int *a` and `int (*a)` the same?

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: There is no difference.  Do note that if you want to declare multiple pointers in one line then you need to use `int *bar, *foo, *baz;`, as `int *bar, foo, baz;` declares one pointer and 2 regular `int`s

Comment: In C++, in general (ignoring the few oddball edge cases, usually involving macros), whitespace is ignored between tokens.